# Can't connect Bluetooth mouse Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, mouse, bluetooth

Recently I bought a Bluetooth mouse and now I have troubles with connecting it to my Windows 7 32bit. I have tried `Control Panel -> Devices and Printers -> Add Device` but no device was found. I also tried `Add Bluetooth Device` button but with the same effect.

First, it perfectly connected and worked on Ubuntu 14 so everything is fine with hardware. I can see Bluetooth module in device manager (along with Microsoft Bluetooth Enumerator) without exclamation mark so I think drivers are fine. My Bluetooth support service is enabled and working.  I've pressed `turn on Bluetooth` button on my laptop. I've ticked `allow Bluetooth devices to connect` in Bluetooth options. I also tried to set system account on LOG tab of Bluetooth support service properties - no effect.

Then I pressed `disable adapter` in Bluetooth settings and somehow it found all my Bluetooth devices I don't know what happened, but my mouse worked for a short period. Then my PC told me that it needs to reboot. After reboooting the mouse didn't work. Again. I opened `Bluetooth devices` I tried to remove and add mouse again but it said that it failed to install `Bluetooth HID device driver`. But at least it saw my Bluetooth devices in that moment. Then I decided to update the Bluetooth drivers, rebooted and now I see nothing. Again.

I've reinstalled drivers but it hasn't helped.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the Microsoft [Designer Bluetooth mouse's specification](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/mice/designer-bluetooth-mouse/7n5-00001#specsColumns-os), you will notice that it does **not** work with Windows 7. It works with Windows 8, 8.1 & 10. Guess they want you to upgrade.

The Microsoft Bluetooth Sculpt Comfort Mouse works with Windows 7, 8, 8.1, & 10 and fits my hand nice.

Comment: I should have read this first. I just brought a bluetooth dongle home... Now it is useless.

Comment: I got the Designer Mouse to work on Windows 7 for a few minutes (yes, a few minutes) then it stopped it working completely. It worked first time, without any configuration needed, on an Android tablet and on Linux 16.04. I'm annoyed that MS are still playing these silly games in 2017.

Answer (score 0):

**1st Method**

To control how your computer pairs with Bluetooth enabled devices

You can set several options for how your computer finds (or is found by) Bluetooth enabled devices.

1. Open Control Panel by clicking the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel.
2. In the Control Panel search box, type Bluetooth, and then click Change Bluetooth settings.
3. In the Bluetooth Settings dialog box, click the Options tab and do any of the following:

   To make your computer discoverable to Bluetooth enabled devices, select the check box for Allow Bluetooth devices to find this computer.

When a Bluetooth enabled computer is in discovery mode, it broadcasts a wireless signal that allows it to be detected by other computers or devices. This is called pairing mode. If you check this box, your computer will still be able to detect Bluetooth enabled devices that are in discovery mode, but they will not be able to detect your computer.

To allow you to add Bluetooth enabled devices to your computer, select the check box for Allow Bluetooth devices to connect to this computer.

**2nd Method**

if you are facing this problem with most of your connected bluetooth devices and you are experiencing this problem after an update.

**Roll Back to a Previous Driver**

1-Click Start

2-type Device Manager, and press Enter.

3-Find and double-click the bluetooth driver of your PC

4-Double Click the bluetooth Driver tab.

5-Click the Roll Back Driver button.

6-A dialog box will ask you to confirm your decision to roll back to a previous driver. Click Yes to begin the roll-back process.

> if there is no previous update

**Uninstall the bluetooth driver**

1- Click Start

2- type Device Manager, and press Enter.

3- Right-click the device, and click Uninstall.

4- Windows will prompt you to confirm the device’s removal. Click OK to remove the driver.

5- After the uninstallation is complete, reboot your computer.

6- If the driver wasn't installed upon restarting , go for the pc manufacturer site and download the Bluetooth driver.

Hope it works:)

Comment: No, nothing helped :(

Answer (score 0):

Hi I know I am a bit late but just wanted to add that the Intel 3165, Intel 7265, and Intel 8260 all support the keyboard and mouse on a fresh Windows 7 install. I would say that it is highly probable that most if not all of Intel's BT / Wifi cards support this however because I don't have them I can not verify that they would work. Note that you need to have both the Wifi drivers and the Bluetooth drivers. Also on non Intel CPUs you will most likely also need chipset drivers installed first. (This happened to me where my i3 laptop worked fine and my FX 8350 required its chipset drivers to see the BT correctly) Hope this helps all.

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/89450/Intel-Dual-Band-Wireless-AC-3165

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/83635/Intel-Dual-Band-Wireless-AC-7265

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/86068/Intel-Dual-Band-Wireless-AC-8260